# debugging beforeSave() in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to debug the beforeSave function, but have no idea of how to do it properly. var_dump and debug functions are just being skipped, even though the debug level is set to two.
What happens when trying to save is that the user is notified that an Event was saved, but in reality it is not.

Here is the code from *'Event'* model:

```
    public function beforeSave($options = array()){

    if($this->calculateWorkingHours($this->data[$this->alias])){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }


}

public function calculateWorkingHours($event){

sscanf($event['start_time'], '%d:%d:%d', $startHour, $startMin, $startSec);
sscanf($event['finish_time'], '%d:%d:%d', $finishHour, $finishMin, $finishSec);

    $pauseHour = $event['pause']['hour'];
    $pauseMin = $event['pause']['min'];

    $startInMinutes = ($startHour * 60 + $startMin);
    $finishInMinutes = ($finishHour * 60 + $finishMin);

    $totalPauseMinutes = ($pauseHour * 60 + $pauseMin);

    $differenceInMinutes = $finishInMinutes - $startInMinutes;
    $finalHours;
    $finalMinutes;

    if($differenceInMinutes > 0){//possitive minutes
        if($totalPauseMinutes < $differenceInMinutes){
            if($event['paid']=='1'){
                $finalHours = floor($differenceInMinutes / 60);
                $finalMinutes = $differenceInMinutes - $finalHours * 60;
            }else{//if breaks are not paid
                $totalMinutes = $differenceInMinutes - $totalPauseMinutes;
                $finalHours = floor($totalMinutes / 60);
                $finalMinutes = $totalMinutes - $finalHours * 60;
            }
            $event['hours'] = $finalHours;
            $event['minutes'] = $finalMinutes;
        }
    }else{//negative minutes
            $totalMinutesPreBreak = floor(((1440 - $startInMinutes)+ $finishInMinutes) + ((1440 - $startInMinutes) + $finishInMinutes))/2;
            if($totalPauseMinutes < $totalMinutesPreBreak){
                if($event['paid']=='1'){//if breaks are paid
                    $finalHours = floor($totalMinutesPreBreak / 60);
                    $finalMinutes = floor($totalMinutesPreBreak - $finalHours * 60);
                }else{//if breaks are not paid
                    $totalMinutes = $totalMinutesPreBreak - $totalPauseMinutes;
                    $finalHours = floor($totalMinutes / 60);
                    $finalMinutes = $totalMinutes - $finalHours * 60;
                }
            $event['hours'] = $finalHours;
            $event['minutes'] = $finalMinutes;  
            }else{
                    $finalHours = floor(((1440 - $startInMinutes) +  $finishInMinutes)/60);
                    $finalMinutes = ((1440 - $startInMinutes) + $finishInMinutes) - $finalHours * 60;
                    $event['hours'] = $finalHours;
                    $event['minutes'] = $finalMinutes;  
            }
    }
        return true;
}
```

Any help or guidance on what could possibly be wrong here or what would be the best way to debug it, is much appreciated.

Comment: It's not saving because the condition in `beforeSave` always returns **false**, since the method `calculateWorkingHours` is only return **true**. Have you noticed this?

Comment: Now I return true in beforeSave() callback, but as long as I do not return anything in calculateWorkingHours(), nothing is being saved. If do return true in calculateWorkingHours(), the events are saved, but none of the logic is being applied. What's the problem here?

Comment: Can you please update your question with the new code? Did you need update the fields `hours` and `minutes` from your events `table`?

Comment: Because you're update the values for $events variable and not for $this->data[$this->alias]. I edited my answer try it with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you always return true in your calculateWorkingHours function and  return false in the beforeSave() callback.

Change for that:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array())
{
    $this->_calculateWorkingHours(); // <-- without parameters, you don't need

    return true;
}

private public function _calculateWorkingHours() // <-- without parameters, you don't need
{
    // all your code
    // and set your data instance
    $this->data[$this->alias]['hours'] = $finalHours;
    $this->data[$this->alias]['minutes'] = $finalMinutes;
    // don't return value this is a only format function
}
```

Comment: Now I return true in beforeSave() callback, but as long as I do not return anything in calculateWorkingHours(), nothing is being saved. If do return true in calculateWorkingHours(), the events are saved, but none of the logic is being applied.
What's the problem here?

Comment: Because you're update the values for $events variable and not for $this->data[$this->alias]. I edited my answer try it with that